# Ruining the family name

Tags: phrases, idioms, idiom-requests, cultural-phrases

1. Is the following correct usage?
   "*They didn't want me to ruin the family name.* "
2. What are some other idiomatic expressions or phrases to say something similar?
   I am aware of "give a bad name" and "one's name is mud".
3. What would be the correct usage of idiom " one's name is mud" in this context?

Comment: ["Disgrace the family name](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disgrace+the+family+name%2C+ruin+the+family+name&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisgrace%20the%20family%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cruin%20the%20family%20name%3B%2Cc0) seems to have more usage.

Comment: @Cascabel that's an important and useful statistic! Thanks...! How can I get such statistics?

Comment: Just click on the link...it takes you to Ngrams by google. Paste in any phrase or word. This is used quite often on this site along with Google.books search.

Comment: Also: They didn't want me to be the bad apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage in line 1

> They didn't want me to ruin the family name

is perfect. And as you say,

> to give the family a bad name

would be fine too.

It's funny to see *One's name is mud*: a wonderfully concise example of bathos!  An idiomatic use of the expression would be,

***They were worried that (if I did such and such) the family name would be mud.***

Other expressions:

***They were worried that (if I did such and such) the family's reputation/standing would/might (thereby!) be ruined.***

Or

***They didn't want me dragging the family name through the dirt***

Or

***...miring the family name / besmirching it / bringing/heaping dishonour upon/on it.***

Or, more plainly,

***They didn't want me to give the family a bad name.***

Comment: Is it correct to say "They were worried that I would ruin the family name"? Also, could you elaborate on how you think "one's name is mud" is an example of Bathos. Needless to say, I hadn't heard of the term "Bathos" until a few seconds ago..

Comment: "One's name" is rather grand: "mud" is very down-to-earth. The rapid 'fall' from posh English to very mundane English makes it bathetic. And quite funny. "One's name is mud"  sounds like the Queen being amusing.

Comment: Ah nice, very subtle. I'm afraid I don't pick up on these itsy bitsies. I'm new to these things. Thanks!

Comment: Your English seems excellent. By the way, I forgot to answer your other point. Yes, "They were worried that I would ruin the family name" is fine. "They feared I would ruin the family name" is also good.

Comment: Oh i like the " feared" bit a bit better! P. S. I know English, I understand it well, but it doesn't flow through me like I want it to. Perhaps writing everyday will help unclog the synapses.

Comment: @user352038 - Good idea.  Practice makes perfect.

Answer (score -1):

As in:

*"They didn't want me to **besmirch** the family name."*

**besmirch**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/besmirch)

> 1. To stain; sully: